# Is there a completely portable way to check for clock_gettime() or comprehensive list of platforms that have it?

Tags: c++, macros, timer, posix

I'm trying to write a small C++ utility library that (among other things) makes the clock_gettime() API available on virtually any platform.*  Basically, I want to check whether clock_gettime() exists, use the native implementation if it's available, and implement it based on other timer API's if it's not available.  Easy, right?  I expected this to be pretty trivial, so naturally, it's turned out to be nearly impossible to do it the way I want. ;)

Here's my problem: If I want users to be able to call the clock_gettime() API transparently, I need my header file to *exactly* detect whether a native declaration/definition is present:

- Optimistic detection doesn't work for obvious reasons: If clock_gettime() is not present but my header's preprocessor macros think it is, it won't be defined, and users will get compiler errors.
- Conservative detection is even worse: If clock_gettime is present and #included but my header doesn't detect it, my own implementation will conflict with it...and I've learned the hard way that compilers won't even complain about clock_gettime() being redefined.  Instead, if you "override" an existing clock_gettime(), your function will be called, sort of, but it will have completely BIZARRE undefined behavior and crash or get into an infinite loop (even if your fallback implementation doesn't have any loops).

So, is there any way reliable way to detect clock_gettime()?  I know that unistd.h is supposed to define the _POSIX_TIMERS macro if clock_gettime() is present...but is this guaranteed for every implementation?  (From my understanding it's not, but I could be wrong.)

- If so, how can I reliably detect whether unistd.h is present (it's not present on Windows, at least in MSVC, and it's present on Linux/BSD's, but there are a lot of minor OS's out there, etc.)?
- If not, is there anything else a simple header file can do to reliably detect it?

If there is no "automatic" solution, is there any reliable, precise list of all platforms that support (or do not support) clock_gettime(), along with their identification macros (for those not at http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/)?  This isn't ideal, since the list could get out of sync as new platforms arise, but it's better than nothing.

I COULD just create a totally new timer API for my own little library, of course.  Then I could conservatively detect clock_gettime() and fall back on other backends as necessary.  This is an obvious solution that would easily work, but...who wants to learn another stupid timer API?  Does the world really need one, just to get around the stupidity of a language that has no built-in mechanisms to detect whether a given function already exists? ;)

*Justification: Why don't I just use C++11's std::chrono?

1. The C++11 chrono interface does not support process timers, which are preferable for certain kinds of benchmarking.  These timers will not be available on every platform, but I'd like to use them on a best-effort basis, and clock_gettime() is the best-known existing interface that supports them.
2. I'd like for this code to run on C++03, so I need a consistent user interface regardless of the underlying language standard or OS...and there's no way I'm going to reimplement the entire C++11 std::chrono interface on platforms that don't have it.  That would be insane.

Comment: _"On POSIX systems on which these functions are available, the symbol _POSIX_TIMERS is defined in <unistd.h> to a value greater than 0."_

Comment: Is it absolutely guaranteed that _POSIX_TIMERS will always be defined if clock_gettime() is present?  (GNU's unistd.h reads, "If these symbols are defined, the corresponding features are
   always available.  If not, they may be available sometimes.")  If so, the problem becomes, how do I detect unistd.h with 100% accuracy?  It isn't present on Windows, at least with MSVC, and it's present on Linux/BSD's, etc., but there are a lot of minor OS's and other potential corner cases, and I'm not aware of any macros that announce its presence.

Comment: I suppose it isn't that important to detect unistd.h with much accuracy: I'll just assume it's there if the platform isn't Windows, and there will be a compile error on any odd platforms missing it (no big deal).  The trickier part is knowing whether the _POSIX_TIMERS macro is absolutely guaranteed to be defined > 0 if clock_gettime() is present, since the worst case scenario is failing to detect a platform that actually has it (especially if it's #included).

Comment: It seems the problem is the other way round : sometimes `_POSIX_TIMERS` macro is set, but `clock_gettime()` is nonetheless not defined (rhel6, centos6, etc.)